# GetGauge Failed to start runner. Timed out connecting to java

Tags: getgauge

Getting Failed to start runner. Timed out connecting to java while running gauge specs

Seems like issue is not resolved till now https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-java/issues/455

```
Gauge version: 1.4.1
Plugins
-------
csharp (0.10.6)
html-report (4.0.12)
java (0.7.15)
json-report (0.3.3)
ruby (0.5.4)
screenshot (0.0.1)
xml-report (0.2.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by setting below 2 configs in gauge.properties

```
runner_connection_timeout 200000
runner_request_timeout 500000
```

https://docs.gauge.org/configuration.html?os=macos&language=javascript&ide=vscode